# Django-rest-framework token auth doesn't work

Tags: django-rest-framework, token, login-required

I'm trying to POST json data to url, decorated with login_required, but django returns redirect to login page

DRF setup:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
```

and `rest_framework.authtoken` in `INSTALLED_APPS`

I can obtain auth token via curl

```
$ curl -X POST -d "{\"username\" : 7, \"password\" : 1}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:9000/extapi/get-auth-token/
{"token":"bc61497d98bed02bd3a84af2235365d0b2b549ff"}
```

But when i POST to the view, decorated with login_required, django returns http 302 with `Location` header pointing to the login page.

```
$ curl -v -X POST -d '{"event":"14","user":"7","action":"1868","unit":"","value":"-1"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Token bc61497d98bed02bd3a84af2235365d0b2b549ff" http://127.0.0.1:9000/zk2015/events/actions/api/uservotejournal/7/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /zk2015/events/actions/api/uservotejournal/7/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Token bc61497d98bed02bd3a84af2235365d0b2b549ff
> Content-Length: 64
> 
* upload completely sent off: 64 out of 64 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
* Server nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Fri, 18 Sep 2015 11:14:31 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: http://127.0.0.1:9000/accounts/login/?next=/zk2015/events/actions/api/uservotejournal/7/
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Cookie
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< ETag: "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
< Set-Cookie: csrftoken=G85fWrKKsIA5a2uGPIn9fS4pqKrS51jK; expires=Fri, 16-Sep-2016 11:14:31 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
< 
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

I've tried to set breakpoints in rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication and rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication, but they were never fired

What is wrong in my setup? Help, please.

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the Authorization in Header in the curl

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"username\" : 7, \"password\" : 1}" -H "Authorization: Token bc61497d98bed02bd3a84af2235365d0b2b549ff" http://127.0.0.1:9000/extapi/get-auth-token/
```

Comment: Quoted request is to obtain auth token, i can't post it there.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that request.user is AnonymousUser in `drf.APIView.dispatch()`, but is defined as authorized user in `drf.APIView.post()` and other similar methods.

This differs from django: request.user is defined as authorized user in `django.views.View.dispatch()`

Also that is the cause, why `django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required` is not compatible whith drf views.